# how to add show a component in vuejs if the page was redirected from a a certain page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

as the title says:)
I want a message to load only if the page is redirected from a certain page.

I think it's related to this.$router or this.$route but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this navigation guard in your component.

```
beforeRouteEnter: function (to, from, next) {
    console.log(to);
    console.log(from.path);
    let pathPre = from.path.split("/");
    if (pathPre[1] === "thepPathYouWantToSeeWhereItComesFrom") {
      //show a component on this basis
    }
  },
```

Try to set **orderComplete** as **slug** in route with `props:true` and catch the route's prop directly in data of vue instance

Use router `name` instead of `path`

```
this.$router.push({ name: "routeNAme",params: { orderComplete: "test" } })
```

```
{
    path: "/routeUrl/:orderComplete",
    name: "routeName",
    component: componentName,
    props: true,
    
},
```

catch directly in data

```
data: function () {
    return {  
      orderComplete: this.$route.params.orderComplete, 
    };
  },
```

This will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is:

- Add a boolean prop in your component (which will decide whether your message gets displayed or not)
- Make sure your page/route can receive this prop (see https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html)
- In your router links that redirect to this page, pass your prop value

Comment: this.$router.push({ path: "/",params: { orderComplete: "test" } }),
but how to access it on the redirected page? this.$route.params.orderComplete or this.$route.params both giviving me undefined when I log it out on the redirected page

Comment: Did you correctly update your route so that it can take this argument, with both `path: "/routeUrl/:yourParam",` and `props: true`? It'd be great if you could share your code.